# on Electron, I cannot eval script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to create Electron app on mac.

So, I create package.json.

```
{
  "name": "electron-simple",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.1"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p> We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
        Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
        and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  win.loadFile('index.html')
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Next, i run `npm start`.

I want to get the window printed **'We are using node 12.13.0, Chrome 80.0.3987.165, and Electron 8.3.0'**

but I got **'We are using node , Chrome , and Electron .'**

what is wrong?

Comment: i read & doing this page https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start

Comment: this is the answer.
i wrote     
webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
}
i can get versions.
thank you.